# JSTL Core fmt:message Tag Dynamic message using bundle/properties file

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jstl

I understand the usage of standard `fmt:message` Tag i.e we define something like this in the JSP:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="ResourceBundles.ValidationErrorMessages" var="errorMessages" />
<fmt:message key="${error.value}" bundle="${errorMessages}" />
```

Suppose error.Value = "MQ2009"

My properties file named "ValidationErrorMessages" has following entry

```
MQ2009 = MQ time out
```

Now my requirement is to have something like

```
MQ2009 = Mq timeout happened for message {messagename}.
```

Can I define the `messagename` variable dynamically? I.e at runtime, `messagename` will be available in request scope and it should be substituted in the properties file.

How can I do this? Do I need a custom tag or does Java EE provides this feature which I am not aware off?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can define properties like

```
MQ2009 = Mq timeout happened for {0}
```

and then

```
<fmt:message key="MQ2009" var="val" >
   <fmt:param value="${valueComingFromSomeParameter}"/>
</fmt:message>
```

and then

```
<c:out value="${val}"/>
```

Comment: You don't have to use `c:out`. Message with parameter will be displayed at `fmt:message` location, if you just remove `var="val"` part. Much more convenient than using additional c:out tag.

Comment: c:out makes sense in combination with escapeXml="true"

Answer (score 5):

In you properties file

```
MQ2009 = Mq timeout happened for message {0}
```

Then you can nest a `<fmt:param value="${messagename}"/>` tag withing `<fmt:message` tag, where `messagename` is in request scope.